# Load schema from the internet

Tags: java, xml, validation, schema

I need to load a [Schema](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) object from the internet, but I don't know how to do it. The URL is like `https://.../.../schema.xsd`.

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc you linked to mentions that "[a] `Schema` object is usually created from `SchemaFactory`."

And `SchemaFactory` has [this nice `newSchema` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema%28java.net.URL%29) that takes an `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Say for instance you want to do XML validation from XSD:

```
static boolean validateXMLAgainstXSD(String xml, String xsd) {
    try {
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```